# $ f:[1,4]\to\mathcal R$ continuous, $ f(1) = f(4)$. Prove $\mathcal { f(x) = f(x + 1.5)}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

> $f:[1,4]\to\mathcal {R}$ is a continuous function and $f(1) = f(4)$. Prove that there exists $x$ where  $\mathcal { f(x) = f(x + 1.5)}$.

I am unsure about how to proceed with the solution to this problem. Any hints are appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define:
$$g(x) = f(x)-f(x+1.5),\quad x\in[1,2.5]$$
Note that $g$ is continuous.  We have that:

\begin{align*}
g(1) &= f(1)-f(2.5) \\
g(2.5) &= f(2.5)-f(4) = f(2.5)-f(1)
\end{align*}

So, we have that $g(1) = -g(2.5)$, so they have opposite parity.  By the intermediate value theorem, for some $x_0\in(1,2.5)$ we have that $g(x_0) = 0$.  For such $x_0$, we have that $$f(x_0)-f(x_0+1.5) = 0\implies f(x_0) = f(x_0+1.5)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = f(x) - f(x + 1.5)$. Then $g(1) = f(1) - f(2.5)$ and $g(2.5) = f(2.5) - f(4) = f(2.5) - f(1)$. Use the intermediate value theorem to conclude that $g(x) = 0$ for some $x$.